# How to correct ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

When I am trying to print

```
import collections 
sentences = collections.defaultdict(list)
unique_suffixes = set()
with open ('file.txt', 'r') as s:
    for line in s:
        start, end = line.split(' ', maxsplit=1)
```

I am throwing "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)". based on the last line of the code.

I found a couple of questions though they have good information they are helpful to me in this case

Comment: It seems that your file contains lines without blank space (maybe only one word..etc)

Answer (score -1):

That is due to the fact that your last line yields a list with two elements.

So the following must solve your issue:

```
import collections 
sentences = collections.defaultdict(list)
unique_suffixes = set()
with open ('input.txt', 'r') as s:
    for line in s:
        data = line.split(' ', maxsplit=1)
        start = data[0]
        end = data[1]
```

Comment: in this case, I got index out of range

Comment: Are you sure that your file uses ' ' as delimiter ? Also try to print third last line using: **print(data)**. This might help you to understand the elements of the list created.

Comment: Yeah, I am sure. It is not working in the linux. Don't how it is working or how it works

Comment: Can you show some lines of your file.txt ?

Comment: I updated the question. It working in other sources however i am trying in Liniux.

Comment: You were trying to open 'file.txt' instead of 'input.txt'.

Comment: figured it. Its about the index position.

Comment: I am not satisfied by the answer by Pax. Since the user is using **maxsplit=1**, then why there is a need of using -1 ? But still if it solves your issue, then Cheers !!

Answer (score -1):

Try this: if line have no space, it will take same word as start and end.

```
import collections 
sentences = collections.defaultdict(list)
unique_suffixes = set()
my_list = []
with open ('file.txt', 'r') as s:
    for line in s:
        data = line.split(' ', maxsplit=1)
        start = data[0]
        end = data[-1]
        my_list.append((start, end))
```

-1 index in python means take the first element in reverse order of the list.

To write it as a csv file:

```
import csv
with open('outfile.csv','w') as f:
    out = csv.writer(f)
    out.writerow(['titleA', 'titleB'])
    out.writerows(my_list)
```

Comment: how do we store the result in a text file

Comment: How do you like to save it? As a plain file or as a csv?

Comment: I would like to save in .csv foramt

Comment: This avoids the error by messing up the input data. How is that helpful?

Comment: The thing is there could be one or more lines with no space. It will need manual inspection. Besides the user hasn't defined what he wants if such case occur. so the simple solution for this problem is this. I hope you agree with me. Otherwise there is another way to skip that particular element. or split by another character.

Comment: @Pax Actually nice idea. Could you please help me with thata